# Check letter case in strings

Tags: oracle

I have varchar column `Name` in table. Rows contain values, for example `'Test', 'tEst', 'TEST', 'test'`. I need my script to retrieve rows, which `Name` value is starts with capital letter and another letters are in lower case. In my example there is the only 1 correct row with `Name` value `'Test'`.
I need to do something like:

```
SELECT
    Name
FROM
    Table
WHERE
    -- condition
```

May be there is some function in Oracte for this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call the [Initcap method](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions065.htm):

```
Where initcap(Name)= Name
```

Answer (score 4):

```
select Name
from Table
where Name = initcap(Name)
```